# Trying to Display Table but it's not being displayed

Tags: php, html

I am using twitter Bootstrap for UI to display the links in the code in the form of table But it's not actually being displayed in the table. Please find the error.

```
<center> <div class="well well-large"> <table>
<?php
    require "config.php";
    require "course_availability_file.php";
    //require "database_queries.php";
    //require "webcrawler.php";

    $course_selected = strtolower( $_POST['coursename1']);
    $available = course_availability($course_selected);
    if ( $available == 0){
        echo "Invalid course"."</br>";
    }
    else {
        // echo "Valid course"."</br>";
        //echo "List of  training links for the course  ".$course_selected ."</br>";
        function retrieveFromDatabase($course_selected){
            require "config.php";
            $con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user ,$db_pass);
            if (!$con){
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);

            $sql_retrieve = "SELECT DISTINCT course_link from course where course_name = '".$course_selected."' AND number < 5 ;";
            $result = mysql_query( $sql_retrieve);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                $link = $row['course_link'];
                echo '<a href="' . $link. '"> ' .$link.' </a>'."</br>";
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            $check_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            mysql_close($con);            
            return $check_num_rows;
        }
        retrieveFromDatabase($course_selected);
    }    
?> </table></div> </center>
```

I'm trying to find out where the error is. All I want to display my links in a table.

Comment: I think you forgot to include <tr> & <td>, pls try.

Comment: please do some basic debugging and at least narrow down the problem.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `echo '<a href="' . $link. '"> ' .$link.' </a>'."</br>";` inside a `<td></td>` element.

`echo '<td><a href="' . $link. '"> ' .$link.' </a>'."</br></td>";`

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple Things:

1. Don't use a `center` tag. Instead, give `margin: 0 auto;`.
2. You missed `<td>`.

#### You cannot add any other tags than `td` under `tr`.

Replace:

```
echo '<a href="' . $link. '"> ' .$link.' </a>'."</br>";
```

With:

```
echo '<td><a href="' . $link. '"> ' .$link.' </a></td>';
```